# Как отключить дублирование слоя в фотошоп?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, photoshop

Я работаю в `Ubuntu`. Чтобы переключиться между рабочими столами, использую `ctrl+alt+rigth(left)`. `Photoshop` установлен в виртуалке.
Итак, я нахожусь в фотошопе, то есть в виртуалку, по инерции вызываю `ctrl+alt +right` чтобы переместиться на другой рабочий стол, но перед этим нужно нажать правый `ctrl` чтобы выйти из виртуалки. Но я забываю и в фотошопе `ctrl+alt+right` дублирует слои, и меняется `psd` макет.
Так вот вопрос, как узнать действие для горячих клавиш `ctrl+alt+right` в фотошопе?
Буду признателен.

Comment: Вроде это было "размер и жесткость кисти". `ctrl+alt+right` Но так работает в Windows в Ubuntu не пробовал через виртуалку.

Comment: Я то понимаю, а мне что делать? Я заметил, что если выбираю пипетку, то слои не дублируются. А вот с текстом - наоборот.

Comment: Может стоит переназначить правый контрол в виртуалбоксе и не трогать фотошоп?

Comment: В виртуалбоксе бывают разные косяки. Фотошоп это все таки программа под винду. А gimp перебиться как-то не сойдет? Как я писал ранее, такого опыта (через виртуалку) у меня не было, в фотошопе в винде работаю когда он нужен, а потом перепрыгиваю назад в ubuntu (у меня стоят параллельно 2 ОС). Подожди, может в сообществе кто-то все ж таки сталкивался с такой проблемой и ответят. Будем ждать, мне и самому интересно.